# Upload image from UIImagePicker to server via php

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, document

I have an UIImageView which load profile picture of the user. I add some UIImagePicker features and now the user able to change the profile picture either by using camera or add from library. This is the code:

```
- (IBAction)cameraAction:(id)sender {
   UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   picker.delegate = self;
   picker.allowsEditing = YES;
   picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

   [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (IBAction)libraryAction:(id)sender {
   UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   picker.delegate = self;
   picker.allowsEditing = YES;
   picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

   [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

#pragma mark - Image Picker Controller delegate methods

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

   UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
   _profilePhoto.image = chosenImage;
   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(_profilePhoto.image, nil, nil, nil);

   [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

   [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Now then, I had php files to upload the current image to server. The problem is, the input parameter for the php is image file name. I do looking around for quite some times and known that to get the image name, first I need to save it to apps document directory and rename it with the name I want later. So can anyone tell me how to save this image to apps document directory, how to get it and how to rename it with the one I want. Thanks in advance

Comment: this may helps you

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400842/uploading-selected-image-from-photo-library-using-afnetworking-and-php][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400842/uploading-selected-image-from-photo-library-using-afnetworking-and-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think that saving the file to document directory will generate you new name. 
When I save something to documents I generate unique file name.

What I do is I pass to web server some generic name like "Upload.png".

Here is some pseudo code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
   UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
   [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];


   ...
   NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(choosenImage);
   NSString *name = @"Uploaded.png"

   // Upload the nsdata to server
   [[PHPServer instance] uploadProfileImage:data named:name];
}
```

Comment: Then could you please tell me how to transform the choosenImage to NSData? Sorry for noob question :p @Krzysztof

Comment: Sorry did not get the question ?

Comment: Sorry, accidentally hit the enter button :P Please review my edited comment

Comment: No worries, please see updated answer. Not sure about your php method implementation, probably multipart encode. If so please have a look at this gist, looks good: 
https://gist.github.com/mombrea/8467128
You need to change Content-Disposition and Content-Type accordingly.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand your code. So what I need to pass to the php is the NSData and NSString instead of attached string to the image itself? Because the php I used only have string post parameter

Comment: It depends what your server expects, most likely it's multipart encode post request, but might be base64 in some json. If it's multipart have a look at one of my previous comments with gist inside.

Comment: if I use encode, is it means I can't choose what name I want for my images? And using this code: NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:choosenImage encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; and pass the newStr to the php??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62235/discussion-between-krzysztof-and-edward).